# How to separate the ajax response data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a ajax function that is returning a set of values from php page.
i need to get the values to that is only required. how can i do this

ajax.js

```
function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM thr';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ther_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['region'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id='lat'>" . $row['corrd_lattitude'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id='lon'>" . $row['corrd_longitude'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

i need only values of

```
 $row['corrd_lattitude'] 
 $row['corrd_longitude']
```

how to get the values of this

Comment: Use JSON in response or other alternative is to concatenate those two values with '-' or some special characters, split them in response.

Answer (score 2):

first you can fetch only required values from table..if i understood correctly you can use following query.

```
  $sql = 'SELECT corrd_lattitude,corrd_longitude FROM thr';
```

it will return only tw0 column value from table.

```
 $json = json_encode(array($row['corrd_lattitude'],  $row['corrd_longitude']));
 echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use json:-----------
=========================================

$sql = "SELECT * FROM thr"; 
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
echo json_encode(array('lats'=>$res['corrd_lattitude'],'lngs'=>$res['corrd_longitude']));
}else{
echo json_encode(array('lats'=>'','lngs'=''));
}
```

here lats and lngs are simply varaiable name to store values inside them and get the value on other page from lats  and lngs varaibale.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify parameters with your request.
In GET method:
`ajax.php?corrd_lattitude=true&corrd_longitude=true`
and in php file you can check this in `$_GET` array ie:

```
<?php
[...]
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  if ($_GET['id'] == true) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  }
  if ($_GET['ther_name'] == true) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['ther_name'] . "</td>";
  }
  if ($_GET['region'] == true) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['region'] . "</td>";
  }
  if ($_GET['phone_no'] == true) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone_no'] . "</td>";
  }
  if ($_GET['address'] == true) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  }
  if ($_GET['corrd_lattitude'] == true) {
    echo "<td id='lat'>" . $row['corrd_lattitude'] . "</td>";
  }
  if ($_GET['corrd_longitude'] == true) {
    echo "<td id='lon'>" . $row['corrd_longitude'] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Better is use json (or plain values) instead of html - your js should pack values into html. It's better for server, client side should build html. Sry for my english.